# Continuous Progress Bar in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to find the best option to create a simple progress bar that I need to be triggered periodically from within another JavaScript script.

Every few minutes, a timer would cause the progress bar to start going from 0 to 100%. Once it reaches 100%, the bar would reset to 0.

I am trying to implement a smooth animated version of the bar, like this one: http://www.webappers.com/progressBar/. (I tried adapting this particular one but I could not get it to work the way I described)

I am looking into the jQuery UI ProgressBar: Is it possible to use it in the manner I have described?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty quick to do with the jQuery UI progress bar, just call this initially:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
```

And this in your other script, probably via `setInterval()`:

```
var percentComplete = 40; //Get the percent
$("#progressbar").progressbar( { value: percentComplete } );
```

Put it together like this:

```
var percentComplete = 0; //Update this in your other script
$("#progressbar").data("progress", setInterval(function() {
  if(percentComplete == 100) {
    percentComplete = 0;
    clearInterval($("#progressbar").data("progress")); //Stop updating
  }
  $("#progressbar").progressbar( { value: percentComplete } );
}, 200));
```

The animated effect keeps it a bit smoother looking as well: [see here for a demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated).  This is done via a single CSS rule, in the demo case:

```
.ui-progressbar-value { background-image: url(images/pbar-ani.gif); }
```