# Javascript function runs long after it is called

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to call a javascript function inside of an ajax call. That function (the `progress` function down below) should be called every time the for loop is run. What actually happens is that `progress` is run as many times as the for loop is run, but `progress` only runs after the rest of the code is completed.

I will post the important parts of the code only. All the variables are defined how they should be. `retData` is a list of objects that are accessed correctly. The only problem I am trying to solve is getting `progress` to run during the for loop's execution and not afterward.

```
function getAllProcess(){
    $.get(processUrl, function(retData){        
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1){
            windowsFillProcessTable(retData);
        }else{
            linuxFillProcessTable(retData);
        }//end else
        $('#divForProcessTable table tbody').append(processHtml);       
    });//end get
}

function windowsFillProcessTable(retData){
    $('#divForProcessTable table tbody #processTableHeaders').append("<th>Session Name</th><th>Session #</th>");
    lengthOfList = retData.list.length;
    step = 100/lengthOfList;

    if (retData.list.length > 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < retData.list.length; i++){      
            numberOfLoaded++;
            progress(step * numberOfLoaded, $('#progressBar')); 

            processHtml += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="' + retData.list[i].pid + '">' + retData.list[i].pid + '</td><td>' + retData.list[i].name + '</td><td>' + retData.list[i].virtualMemorySize + '</td><td>' + 
            retData.list[i].user + '</td><td>' + retData.list[i].cpuTime + '</td><td>' + retData.list[i].status + '</td><td>' + retData.list[i].sessionName + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + retData.list[i].sessionNumber + '</td></tr>';                          
        }//end for
    }//end if for length
    else{
        processHtml = '<tr><td colspan="15">There are no processes matching that expression</td></tr>';
    }
}

//Loading bar action
function progress(percent, $element) {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(new Date());
    var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
}
```

Comment: The for loop never allows the DOM to update.

Comment: @epascarello Oh. That would make sense. Do you know of a way to force the DOM to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it might be possible through using workers, but I couldn't figure out how to use them right. As of right now, I am going to mark this as my answer because no one else has given any guidance on how to use a worker thread to update the DOM asynchronously. Also, with workers, you do not have access directly to the DOM. List of what you cannot access with workers: 
The DOM (it's not thread-safe)
The window object
The document object
The parent object

I got this from: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem you are actually facing is not that `progress` is run once when the `for` loop finishes, but that the `div` where you are trying to reflect that change is updated only when the `windowsFillProcessTable` finishes executing. Since JavaScript is single threaded ([for now](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/)) the execution of `windowsFillProcessTable` blocks every other processing, including DOM update.

You'll have to find an alternative scheme to make the update to your progress bar. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497350/continuous-progress-bar-in-javascript) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079681/update-a-jquery-progress-bar-added-at-runtime) for possible options.

Comment: You're right. I will need to find a different way. When I find how to do it, I will post the answer. Thank you for guiding me to some helpful links!